# Robolectric 3.0 Nullpointer on DefaultPackageManager.getActivityInfo()

Tags: android, robolectric

I try to create a Robolectric test (3.0-rc02) for the following Activity:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private NotificationFragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
}
}
```

The test is looking like this:

```
@Config(manifest = IConfig.MANIFEST_PATH, emulateSdk = IConfig.SDK_VERSION, reportSdk = IConfig.SDK_VERSION)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AbstractFragmentTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Robolectric.buildActivity(NotificationActivity.class).setup().visible();
    }
```

where SDK_VERSION = 18.

When running the test, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.builder.DefaultPackageManager.getActivityInfo(DefaultPackageManager.java:164)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.getActivityInfo(ActivityController.java:65)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:51)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:121)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:309)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:47)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
    at com.viae.common.view.AbstractFragmentTest.test(AbstractFragmentTest.java:31)
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong over here?

**Issue solved**

Using FragmentActivity in stead of ActionBarActivity did the trick to me.
My main logic is in a fragment (DialogFragment) inside the activity. Both activities are supporting the DialogFragment, so for my functional tests it doesn't matter which of the 2 parent activities I use.

Comment: Is it run from command line or from AS? What is your project structure? Does your debug build change `applicationId`?

Comment: I solved the issue now by changing from ActionBarActivity to FragmentActivity.

Comment: I run it within eclipse

Comment: Add your own answer! Help others

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity) instead